# What is this brown mass on this egg?

Tags: food-safety, eggs

I boiled an egg and while eating it I found this brown mass. It's not gooey - I tested whether I could squeeze it out, but it just ripped with the rest of the egg white.

[image]

Update: another egg in this batch of 24 had a similar spot. Here are some more pictures:

As you can see in this picture, this time I was able to squeeze out the brown mass:[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

That could be what's known as a meat spot.
When a hen is laying an egg, sometimes pieces are sloughed off on the process down the ovary.
Although this is unusually large for a meat spot, it could be something like a blood clot that was sloughed off during the process.

It is usually safe to eat, but I wouldn't recommend it.